# Nuxt Capacitor Android, But not static site

Tags: nuxt.js, capacitor

There's a variable     `"webDir": "dist",` in the ***capacitor.config.json***
The "**dist**" only generated for static site But all the routes of my app are generated dynamically!

I need a way to build a android project without "nuxt generate"

Comment: you can specify the `webDir` to be the `.nuxt` folder created by `nuxt build` however you will encounter the next error where capacitor looks for `index.html` which Nuxt doesn't create. That is where I am at now. Did you manage to get this working?